# RangeSelector изменение шаблона

Tags: c#, uwp, rangeslider

В UWP есть `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` в нем есть RangeSelector, есть ли возможность изменить шаблон этого RangeSelectora?

Comment: Была такая ситуация с busy indicator. Нашел его исходный код и переопределил стиль для busy indicator. Лучшего решения для себя так и не нашел

Comment: Ну я так же сделал просто думал где то можно изменить исходный код Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

Comment: можно качнуть исходники с гитхаба, поменять их, перекомпилировать, если нужно будет, то подписать сборку. По моему это исходники https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit